# Add system packages to PDE runtime configuration

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-pde

I created an eclipse run configuration for a number of bundles. One of the bundles has a dependency to the following packages:

```
com.sun.mirror.apt,
com.sun.mirror.declaration,
com.sun.mirror.type,
com.sun.mirror.util
```

I believe these are part of the Sun Java JVM. When I add these packages as system packages to a Felix container, the bundle is loaded fine by that container.

However, I was unable so far to find out, how I can configure these packages as additional system packages for a run configuration in eclipse (I found how eclipse as a whole can be made aware by changing the config.ini).

EDIT: It seems that these classes are in the system library tools.jar. Or in my case, as I am using Mac OS X, they could be in classes.jar?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513083/depending-on-com-sun-javadoc-from-tools-jar-sun-jdk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSGi specification defines a property called "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra" (explained in paragraph 4.2.2 that deals with launching properties) that allows you to specify extra packages that should be exported by the framework. Add your packages to that property in your run configuration and it should work.