# How to import com.sun.javadoc.* in eclipse?

Tags: java, javadoc

Importing com.sun.javadoc eclipse report me this error "The import com.sun.javadoc cannot be roselved" it seems the package is not installed. Looking at the web sitehttp://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec/index.html?com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html only the API are displayed but I cannot download anything. How can I do

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to import it?  Are you actually trying to extend the framework itself?  You don't need to import the javadoc library to use javadoc comments within your code, only to parse those comments (e.g. run the javadoc command on your project)

Comment: I need to parse a java class to convert it in XML format

Comment: for that, take a look at http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What I usually do is, in Eclipse preferences, I define an Installed JRE called "JDK X.Y.Z" and include `tools.jar` as part of it libraries.  Then I change the project preferences to use that JRE "JDK X.Y.Z".

The other approach is to simply add `tools.jar` to your project's library or point to it in the project path.

Comment: This is what I was looking for thancks Bert

Comment: @Pool : You are my savior , kudos to you !

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Tools.jar from the JDK install into your project's build path.

Right click your project in the Package Explorer, and go to properties. On the left, click "Java Build Path". Go to the "Libraries" tab and click "Add External JARs". Navigate to your JDK install and go to the LIB folder. Select tools.jar, and hit okay.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html#com.sun.javadoc

The JDK's tools.jar is not typically included in Eclipse project class paths.  You should avoid using com.sun.* code if you can.

Comment: There might be better ways of doing this, but the [Oracle JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html) has examples showing how to directly call these classes._Package com.sun.javadoc
The Doclet API (also called the Javadoc API) provides a mechanism for clients to inspect the source-level structure of programs and libraries, including javadoc comments embedded in the source._

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually have a JDK installed, or maybe just an JRE?

Also see [Depending on com.sun.javadoc from tools.jar (Sun JDK) in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1513083/60462).

Comment: I included the tools.jar from the jdk/lib directory and I resolved. Thank you anyway